# azureAD to On premises ad sync

Tags: active-directory, entra-id

I have a client with office 365 azure ad instalation. lets call it blabla.com. now the client need a local ad infrastructure. they have around 40 users . im planing on creating a dc and then create a local domain. then use azure ad sync.

since the domain name in o365 is blabla.com can i use corp.blabla.com for local domain name ? what are the best pracices here ?

has anyone done this kind of operation ? what are the most comom pitfalls i must pay attention to ?

thanks all

j

Answer (score 2):

1. You can't sync your existing Office 365 users to your on premises AD... BUT... you can match and sync your on premises AD users to your existing Office 365 users once you create your on premises AD users.
2. The two directories are completely unrelated to each other as far as the domain name goes. The important thing is to create your on premises users with the same UPN suffix as your Office 365 UPN suffix so that the on premises users can be matched to the existing Office 365 users.

For Example: if your Office 365 UPN suffix is **blabla.com** then you need to create an on premises UPN suffix named **blabla.com** and assign that to all of your on premises AD users. The AD domain can be named anything... like ad.corp.com, so long as your on premises AD users have a UPN suffix that matches their Office 365 UPN suffix.

Comment: I would like to ask about this related case: a laptop is joined to Azure-AD and the user logs in with a PIN-code. The on-premise AD is synced with Azure-AD in the way you mention. When the user logs in, the laptop is not logged in to the on-premise AD, right? There are no policies applied, no loginscripts, etc. A LOB-application that connects to a on-premise SQL-server might not accept this user with integraded Windows-authentication because of that. What is a solution then?